# Overriding font location in CutyCapt

Tags: qt, fonts, cutycapt

I'm working with an application, CutyCapt, which just converts web pages to PDF using QtWebkit. We're driving it programmatically to export emails to PDF.

As part of trying to make our test suite sane, generating as consistent output as possible across multiple platforms, I'm trying to ensure that everything which is doing print-like operations has access to all the required fonts. As such, a directory of fonts is checked in next to all the test files.

All the other implementations of PDF export so far are pure Java and we have essentially shoehorned in ways to specify a directory of additional fonts for every exporter. But I can't figure out how to do the same sort of thing for CutyCapt.

Digging through the Qt docs, I can't find any word on the matter. Various posts on forums and tickets have resulted in discovering `QT_QWS_FONTDIR` and `QT_QPA_FONTDIR` but setting these doesn't appear to change the behaviour.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

In order to manage fonts in a Qt application you can use a `QFontDatabase` which provides information about the fonts available in the underlying window system.
The class has several static members that will allow you, among other things, to programmatically add fonts to your application. You can even embed fonts as resources and still be able to load them.

I'll post a real world example. Suppose you downloaded a font family called "Helvetica Neue" and you want to make it available to your application. The embedded approach would be like follows.

1 - Add all .ttf files as resources.

2 - Call `addApplicationFont()` for each .ttf file.

```
QFontDatabase fontDB;
fontDB.addApplicationFont(":/fonts/Helvetica Neue/Helvetica Neue CE 35 Thin.ttf");
fontDB.addApplicationFont(":/fonts/Helvetica Neue/Helvetica Neue CE 36 Thin Italic.ttf");
fontDB.addApplicationFont(":/fonts/Helvetica Neue/Helvetica Neue CE 55 Roman.ttf");
fontDB.addApplicationFont(":/fonts/Helvetica Neue/Helvetica Neue CE 56 Italic.ttf");
fontDB.addApplicationFont(":/fonts/Helvetica Neue/Helvetica Neue CE 75 Bold.ttf");
fontDB.addApplicationFont(":/fonts/Helvetica Neue/Helvetica Neue CE 56 Bold Italic.ttf");
```

3 - You're done. You can now do the following to check the "Helvetica Neue" font family is there.

```
for (int i = 0; i < fontDB.families().size(); ++i)
    qDebug() << fontDB.families().at(i);
```

So, wherever you set a font "Helvetica Neue" in your program it will be found.

This is pretty obvious but if you don't want to load the fonts into your application one by one it's quite easy to manage. For example the following (and naive) code snippet will attempt to load all files in a specific folder as if they were fonts.

```
QDir myFontsDirectory("myfonts");
if (!myFontsDirectory.exists())
{
    qWarning("Cannot find the directory");
}
else
{
    QFileInfoList list = myFontsDirectory.entryInfoList();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
    {
        QFileInfo fileInfo = list.at(i);
        fontDB.addApplicationFont(fileInfo.filePath());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm so I'd have to fork it and add all fonts from custom dirs. I guess I will file this under "last resort" as it does seem like it will work.

Comment: You can also attempt to register `QT_QWS_FONTDIR` environment variable (something I also tried without any luck in the past) or try to do system wide stuff with the system fonts folder that can be obtained with: `QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::FontsLocation)`. But I don't really favor that and I don't really think it would be a straightforward solution. I've faced the same problem like you and I'm still believing that managing application fonts with `QFontDatabase` is preferable.